# How to get 4 finger volume up/down gesture using touché?

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch

Can anyone help me out in adding 4 finger gesture for volume up/down using touché and what should be the command for this.
[touché installation](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/06/multi-touch-gestures-ubuntu-20-04/)

[image]